# How to push an array to an existing session in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Prior to my previous question I have come up with another idea to push array of items in a single session

For instance I have a session `session('products')`

Now what I have, are sets of items for instance.

```
Name=Item1
Class=Good

Name=Item2
Class=Bad

Name=Item3
Class=Good

Name=Item4
Class=Bad
```

I learnt that

```
session()->put('products.name', $name);
session()->put('products.class', $class);
```

This would simply put items to it but When I try to put another array to session, it just replaces the values,

Thus I tried to use `push()` method

```
session()->push('products.name', $name);
session()->push('products.class', $class);
```

But it shows that `[] operator not supported for strings` Does anyone have solution to this?

I am new to laravel and learning!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suppose it can be something like:

```
// set products.name as array
session()->put('products.name', []);


// somewhere later
session()->push('products.name', $name1);

// somewhere else later
session()->push('products.name', $name2);
```

Comment: Yess this works! I made an `if` condition that if the `products session` is `nul`l then `session()->put('products.name', []);`. Now I can `push` items into it thank you